# Stange behaviour of vector c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question for you. Let's say I have a vector of AwesomeData and the class AwesomeData contain a vector of AwesomeData. If I try to access the vector inside the first vector, it doesn't work correctly. As I know this is not clear here a much more explicit example :

```
struct AwesomeData
{
public:
    AwesomeData()
    : beautifulInt(3)
    {}

    int beautifulInt;
    vector<AwesomeData> someVector;
};

int main()
{
    vector<AwesomeData> tata;
    AwesomeData toto;

    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());
    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());
    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());

    tata.push_back(AwesomeData());
    tata.push_back(toto);
    tata.push_back(AwesomeData());


    // So, now tata should containt the data of someVector of toto (3 default    
    // AwesomeData). Instead of that, his capacity is equal to 3, but his
    // size = 0. So, what's wrong ?
    tata = tata[1].someVector;
}
```

But hey, it's not all ! I found a work around, but I don't know why it work.

```
struct AwesomeData
{
public:
    AwesomeData()
        : beautifulInt(3)
    {}

    int beautifulInt;
    vector<AwesomeData> someVector;
};

int main()
{
    vector<AwesomeData> tata;
    AwesomeData toto;

    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());
    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());
    toto.someVector.push_back(AwesomeData());

    tata.push_back(AwesomeData());
    tata.push_back(toto);
    tata.push_back(AwesomeData());


    // If we use a second vector to temporaly stock the vector of toto,
    // everything work as expected
    vector<AwesomeData> tempVector;

    tempVector = tata[1].someVector;
    tata = tempVector;
}
```

So anyone has a idea ?

Big thanks

Comment: [`tata.size()` is `3` here](http://ideone.com/7hsoV5).

Comment: Somehow I doubt that this is the actual cause, but your code is illegal, has undefined behavior, and will fail to compile with some compilers.  You cannot create a vector of an incomplete type.

Comment: @sftrabbit Beat me to it.

Comment: Also, how does it make sense to have a vector of the own class as member? The whole program design seems completely flawed. If it would make any sense it would have been a vector of pointers or similar (nodes in a linked list, graph etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

standard containers do not allow you to instantiate them with in-complete types. In your example `AwesomeData` is not completely defined when you try to instantiate a `std::vector<AwesomeData>`.

To achieve this you could take a look at the `boost::container` library.

see [Boost::container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html)